# Using backbone with compressed views via Uglify

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, webpack, uglifyjs

I have this view in `activity.view.js`:

```
var ViewActivity = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#Activity',

    events:{
        'change #grade': 'gradeChanged'
    },

    initialize: function(params){
        _.bindAll(this, 'gradeChanged', 'render');
        this.model = new MyModel(params)
        this.render();
    },

    gradeChanged: function(){
    },

    render: function(){
    }
});
```

In the HTML, I call the view as:

```
<script>
var view = new ViewActivity({
    foo: 'bar'
}); 
</script>
```

Here, all without problems. The problem comes when I try to use webpack's plugin `UglifyJS` to compress all javascript. After compress `activity.view.js` the ViewActivity object is not available to instantiate as I did because of the compressed code:

```
!function(r){var n={};function e(t){if(n[t])return ..
```

> Browser console: ViewActivity is undefined

How do I make use of ViewActivity  when the code is compressed? Thanks in advance

I forgot to mention that I used the following config but the compressed code remains the same:

```
plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
            keep_classnames: true,
            keep_fnames: true,
            mangle: {
                reserved: ["VistaPago"]
            }
        }
    })
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The minifier thinks `ViewActivity` is a local variable, hence it's safe to compress its assigned name. You can work around that by saying:

```
window.ViewActivity = Backbone.View.extend({
```

Or you can define a factory method inside `activity.view.js`  to instantiate it:

```
window.createActivityView(foo) {
    return new ViewActivity({
                             bar: foo
    });
}
```